# How do I declare LPCGUID in VB6?

Tags: winapi, vb6

I would like to use [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerpowersettingnotification) in VB6.

It expects a GUID as a parameter:

```
HPOWERNOTIFY RegisterPowerSettingNotification(
  HANDLE  hRecipient,
  LPCGUID PowerSettingGuid,
  DWORD   Flags
);
```

I don't find any examples on how to do that in VB6. Specifically, I don't understand how to define this GUID. I guess it's not just a string.

This is what I could come up with so far:

```
Private hPowerSrc&
Private hBattCapacity&
Private hMonitorOn&
Private hPowerScheme&

Private Const DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE As Long = 0

Private Sub pInitPower()

    hPowerSrc = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(Me.hWnd, GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE)

    hBattCapacity = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(Me.hWnd, GUID_BATTERY_PERCENTAGE_REMAINING, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE)

    hMonitorOn = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(Me.hWnd, GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE)

    hPowerScheme = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(Me.hWnd, GUID_POWERSCHEME_PERSONALITY, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE)

End Sub
```

How would I complete this sample including the API declaration and GUIDs and calling it?

Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/guiddef/ns-guiddef-guid. `(byval long, byref GUID, byval long) as long`.

Comment: [How to use GUID in VB6](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?892353-How-to-use-GUID-in-VB6&s=051c8c72f9b641ea2ae957ddd6c2dfa5&p=5526073&viewfull=1#post5526073)

Comment: among vb6 authors not all are alive i think. bug report may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [How to use GUID in VB6](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?892353-How-to-use-GUID-in-VB6&s=051c8c72f9b641ea2ae957ddd6c2dfa5&p=5526073&viewfull=1#post5526073), try something like this:

```vb
Private hPowerSrc&
Private hBattCapacity&
Private hMonitorOn&
Private hPowerScheme&

Private Const DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE As Long = 0

Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

Private Declare Function CLSIDFromString Lib "ole32" (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef clsid As GUID) As Long

Private Declare Function RegisterPowerSettingNotification Lib "user32" (ByVal hRecipient As Long, ByRef PowerSettingGuid As GUID, ByVal Flags As Long) As Long;

Private Sub pInitPower()

    Dim GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE as GUID
    Dim GUID_BATTERY_PERCENTAGE_REMAINING as GUID
    Dim GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON as GUID
    Dim GUID_POWERSCHEME_PERSONALITY as GUID

    CLSIDFromString StrPtr("{5D3E9A59-E9D5-4B00-A6BD-FF34FF516548}"), GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE
    CLSIDFromString StrPtr("{A7AD8041-B45A-4CAE-87A3-EECBB468A9E1}"), GUID_BATTERY_PERCENTAGE_REMAINING
    CLSIDFromString StrPtr("{02731015-4510-4526-99E6-E5A17EBD1AEA}"), GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON
    CLSIDFromString StrPtr("{245d8541-3943-4422-b025-13A784F679B7}"), GUID_POWERSCHEME_PERSONALITY

    hPowerSrc = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(Me.hWnd, GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE)

    hBattCapacity = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(Me.hWnd, GUID_BATTERY_PERCENTAGE_REMAINING, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE)

    hMonitorOn = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(Me.hWnd, GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE)

    hPowerScheme = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(Me.hWnd, GUID_POWERSCHEME_PERSONALITY, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE)

End Sub
```

Comment: One can also make a good case for `ByRef PowerSettingGuid As Any` here.  Then you can pass a null pointer or a Byte or Long array's first element as needed. A UDT for GUIDs is a little over the top really, but we all tend to do it anyway.  More documentation than significance there.

Comment: Thank you. I am still trying to check the window message so that I can actually try it out. I have posted a new question about it because I don't understand yet how to deal with the message.